# How can I serve generated phpDocumentor docs from Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, phpdoc, continuous-delivery

So I'm using phpDocumentor 3 to generate documentation for my Laravel 7 project,

and was wondering if I could serve this documentation (static files) from Laravel in order to make it available only to **authorized users**.

I would like to be able to update the documentation through my **CI/CD**, so I can't just modify manually the generated documentation.

I think that I might have to write my own template (https://docs.phpdoc.org/3.0/guide/guides/templates.html) for that but I'm not sure whether the documentation is incomplete or if I'm missing something because I have no idea how to create a template. Any suggestions, guides or tutorials that can help me achieve this please ?
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can include the phpDoc generation within your CI/CD script:

first install the `phpDocumentor` on the production, then generate using this command:

```
phpDocumentor -d . -t storage/docs/
```

> Note: the `storage` path maybe is **gitIgnored** if you plan to
> generate the phpDocs, not on the production server, you have to be
> sure that the folder will be **pushed to the production**

add this to the `config/filesystem.php` 'disks':

```
'local-docs' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => storage_path('docs'),
        ],
```

and add the following in your routes file (`routes/web.php`)

```
Route::get('/docs/{url?}', function ($url) {
    $resp = response(Storage::disk('local-docs')->get($url));
    $resp->header('content-type', GuzzleHttp\Psr7\MimeType::fromFilename($url));
    return $resp;

})->where('url', '(.*)')->middleware('auth');
```

> be sure you haven't any other route with the `docs` prefix

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, I didn't have the time to test it yet, once I do I will accept the answer and give you the bounty, thank you !

Comment: I've tested it ^^' It kind of work, but the css doesn't apply, I did a quick comparison and find out that despite of the css being downloaded it is not applied, I think it might have to do something with the missing response headers ? like on a normal page I have 'content-type: text/css' but on docs the css are returned as 'content-type: text/html', so I've added to your answer some headers and it's working now, thank you!

Comment: `Route::get('/docs/{url?}', function ($url) {
    $resp = response(Storage::disk('local-docs')->get($url));
    if(preg_match('/(.*.css)/', $url))
        $resp->header('content-type', 'text/css');
    else if(preg_match('/(.*.js)/', $url))
        $resp->header('content-type', 'application/javascript');
    return $resp;
})->where('url', '(.*)');`

Comment: the main types that may impact the docs are javsacript/css so I didn't cover the rest of the cases, but I'm sure there is a better way to do that, if you can update your answer with my code (or a better solution) it would be great, thank you !

Comment: @hereForLearning thanks, I have updated my answer with your mime-type correction. I am glad that your problem has resolved

Comment: ok last update (I hope ^^'): we can get the MimeType from the extension without the if/else as follow : $resp->header('content-type', GuzzleHttp\Psr7\MimeType::fromFilename($url));

Comment: awesome :+1 it looks better now. thanks @hereForLearning . I have searched for it, but I couldnt found your solution :+1